# How can I convert 20:13-02-05T13:45:17-0500 to a MySQL datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In PHP, how can I convert a date/time string in the format 20:13-02-05T13:45:17-0500 to a valid MySQL datetime so I can store it?

So far I've tried

```
$date_id = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_id));
```

Comment: By writing some code ;) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried several things but couldn't make it work .

Comment: Where is this date coming from? `20:13` does not look standard to me.

Comment: @Salman from a JSON API . I think it's somehow formated to work with javascript .

Comment: The date does not seem to follow any standards. You can still get it to work with `strtotime` by removing the first `:` using `str_replace`. But double check with the API vendor to see if their API is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// convert non-standard year format 20:13 to 2013
$date = preg_replace ('/^(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', '$1$2', $date_id);

$timestamp = strtotime ($date);
echo date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$date_to_store = '20:13-02-05T13:45:17-0500';
$date_for_mysql = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime( $date_to_store ) );
```

Then in your query, just insert the `$date_for_mysql`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`timestamp`) VALUES ('" . $date_for_mysql . "')");
```

Of course you should be using prepared statements, but this is just to illustrate the date conversion.

Comment: I get invalid dates such  1970-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
explode(your_time);
```

This should get you the time chunks, and then use date and mktime.

```
date(Your_preferred_format, mktime(chunks_as_per_mktime));
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work .

Comment: what is chunks_as_per_mktime ?

Comment: I think there should be a specific format for mysql datetime not a preferred one .

Comment: Sure there is, for example if YOUR mysql date time format is 2013-05-25 10:15:59, mktime will take the values you give it and return you the date/time in this format, see php.net/mktime

Comment: it doesn't work . Provides invalid date / time such 1970-01-01 00:00:00 same as @CyberBrian's solution

Comment: in your current format, I don't what what is the year,month,day, hour, minute, second. First get these from your current format and then use them in mktime();

Comment: Here you go http://www.anchorx.com/ali/2013/02/06/php-date-format-example/